# List of coordinate pairs from an array in 20 x 20 chunks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coordinates

I have a 2d array of 300 x 200 from an image. I would like to generate a list of coordinate pairs for every 20 x 20 chunks until the end of the array.

To generate the coordinate pairs from a grid is straight forward, but I'm stuck at how to iterate the 20 x 20 chunks in an array. I'm new to numpy and arrays.

```
w, h = 300, 200
coordinates = [(x, y) for x in xrange(w) for y in xrange(h)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code generates a list `totalList` in which each element itself is a list of all coordinates in a specific 20x20 block. You can reduce this to another list comprehension if you like, but I personally don't think that's very readable.

```
w, h = 300, 200
blockSize = 20
totalList = []

for xStart in xrange(0, w, blockSize):
    xEnd = min(xStart+blockSize, w)
    for yStart in range(0, h, blockSize):
        yEnd = min(yStart+blockSize, h)
        partCoords = [(x,y) for x in xrange(xStart, xEnd) for y in xrange(yStart, yEnd)]
        totalList.append(partCoords)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate through the original array you can do something like this:

```
w,h = 6,4
n = 2                   #Height of window
m = 2                   #Width of window
k = h / n               #Must divide evenly
l = w / m               #Must divide evenly

data = np.random.randint(0,90,(h,w))
data
[[45 39 36 25 30 21]
 [48 27 46 48 20 87]
 [19 20 59 27 41 52]
 [52 11 42 30 85 49]]

for h in xrange(k):
    for w in xrange(l):
        print data[h*n:(h+1)*n,w*m:(w+1)*m]


[[45 39]
 [48 27]]
[[36 25]
 [46 48]]
[[30 21]
 [20 87]]

[[19 20]
 [52 11]]
[[59 27]
 [42 30]]
[[41 52]
 [85 49]]
```

You can switch the order of the loop to have different windows occurring first.

You can also pre generate all indices:

```
inds = np.arange(w*h).reshape(k,n,l,m).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(k,l,n*m)
#The final reshape can be reshape(k*l,n*m) if you do not want a double loop. 

for h in xrange(k):
    for w in xrange(l):
        print np.take(data,inds[h,w])

[45 39 48 27]
[36 25 46 48]
[30 21 20 87]
[19 20 52 11]
[59 27 42 30]
[41 52 85 49]
```

You also have this option:

```
[np.split(x,k,axis=0) for x in np.split(data,l,axis=1)]

[[array([[45, 39],
       [48, 27]]), 
array([[19, 20],
       [52, 11]])], 
[array([[36, 25],
       [46, 48]]), 
array([[59, 27],
       [42, 30]])], 
[array([[30, 21],
       [20, 87]]), 
array([[41, 52],
       [85, 49]])]]
```

Note for the above I switched the output ordering, you can use:

```
[np.split(x,l,axis=1) for x in np.split(data,k,axis=0)]
```

to return the same as all the others, I just wanted to give this as an example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly.

```
w, h = 300, 200
coordinates = [(x,y) for x in xrange(0, w, 20) for y in xrange(0, h, 20)]
```